# Why can't I use Timer to perform a declaration of a variable

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

Since I need to have the latest data in the database through non-stop repeated declarations. I want to achieve my goal by setting timer. My current idea is to use this way, but this does not work.

Can someone give me advice?

```
var timer = new PeriodicTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

while (await timer.WaitForNextTickAsync())
{
    double H = Model.LastOrDefault().Ax;
    double V = Model.LastOrDefault().Ay;
}
```

Comment: What do mean by "does not work"? There's nothing obvious in this Code, outside the custom Timer implemenation. But even that should be no problem.

Comment: What is not working? Are you receiving an error?

Comment: Describe what do you expect to happen, and what actually happens.

Comment: @Fildor I'm very sorry, I didn't describe it clearly, I wanted to use the two variables H and V outside the loop, but I can't use it.

Comment: @DarkBee I'm very sorry, I didn't describe it clearly, I wanted to use the two variables H and V outside the loop, but I can't use it, and someone below has guessed what I mean

Comment: @Dialecticus I'm very sorry, I didn't describe it clearly, I wanted to use the two variables H and V outside the loop, but I can't use it, and someone below has guessed what I mean

Comment: Because of the jet lag, I replied so late, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that you wish to use your variables `H` and `V` in code that is not in your `while` loop.

In the code:

```
var timer = new PeriodicTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

while (await timer.WaitForNextTickAsync())
{
    double H = Model.LastOrDefault().Ax;
    double V = Model.LastOrDefault().Ay;
}
```

`H` and `V` are only in scope within the while loop and as such can only be used within it. In other words they are local to the `while` loop and not outside of it e.g.:

```
while (await timer.WaitForNextTickAsync())
{
    double H = Model.LastOrDefault().Ax;
    double V = Model.LastOrDefault().Ay;
    double Sum = H+V; // okay
}
double Sub = H-V;//Not possible as H & V are out of scope being local to the while loop
```

If you wish to use `H` and `V` elsewhere then they must be declared in such as place as that they are still in scope (accessible) where you wish to use them.

```
var timer = new PeriodicTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
double H=0.0;
double V=0.0;
while (await timer.WaitForNextTickAsync())
{
    H = Model.LastOrDefault().Ax;
    V = Model.LastOrDefault().Ay;
        double Sum = H+V; // okay
}
double Sub = H-V;//okay as well
```

Comment: One *could* actually dynamically create objects only when the timer fires, by assigning to a pointer/reference that's originally initialized with null. That would make particular sense if, like here, there is a bunch of data belonging together. One should bundle that in a class and allocate it when the timer fires. The pointer/reference can be used to see whether the timer has fired (is it null or not?).

Comment: @ChrisBD I get it, thank you for the detailed answer, let me learn something new again, thank you very much!!